# How to flush zend_form to multiple entities

Tags: doctrine-orm, associations, zend-framework2, entities, flush

I'm struggling with flushing my **zend_form** to 2 entities. In total I've 3 entities. User, Address and Country. Country is not interesting because it has standard values where only the ID come into Address. My add-action works good (only when I keep my address/country empty, it puts a new record in the database so I've to fix this). But my edit only flushes my latest bind. My edit-action:

```cs
/**
     * Edit action for single user
     * 
     * @return route zfcadmin/user/add
     * @return route zfcadmin/user
     * @return array(id, form, flashMessages)
*/
public function editAction()
{
    $id = (int)$this->getEvent()->getRouteMatch()->getParam('id');
    if (!$id) {
        return $this->redirect()->toRoute('zfcadmin/user/', array('action' => 'add'));
    }
    //Get user with the id (given in URL), and pick his address(es)
    $user = $this->getEntityManager()->find('User\Entity\User', $id);
    $addresses = $user->addresses;

    $form = new UserForm();

    //Set country values out of the entity
    $form = $this->fillCountrySelectbox($form);
    $form->bind($user);

    //Get addresses from the user, and bind it to the $form
    foreach($addresses as $address) {
        //If user has address, bind the addresses
        if(isset($address)) {
            $form->bind($address);
        }
    }

    $form->get('save_goback')->setAttribute('value', 'Save');
    $form->get('save')->setAttribute('value', 'Save & Stay');

    $request = $this->getRequest();
    if ($request->isPost()) {
        //Set the inputfilter on the input values
        $inputFilter = new InputFilter();

        //Set filters from different entities
        $inputFilter = $user->setFilters($inputFilter);
        $inputFilter = $address->setFilters($inputFilter);

        //Set the inputFilter on the form
        $form->setInputFilter($inputFilter);

        $form->setData($request->getPost());
        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $form->bindValues();

            //set complete country object in address entity.
            $country = $this->getEntityManager()->find('User\Entity\Country', $form->get('country')->getValue());
            $address->__set('country', $country);

            //Set country Null when no country was selected, otherwise it conflict with country entity (because no '' is set)
            if($address->country == '') {
                $address->country = NULL;
            }

            //Set modifier (current user)
            $address->__set('last_modifier_id', $this->zfcUserAuthentication()->getIdentity()->getId());

            $this->flashMessenger()->addMessage('User saved');

            $this->getEntityManager()->flush();

            if ($this->getRequest()->getPost('save_goback')) {
                return $this->redirect()->toRoute('zfcadmin/user');
            }
        }
    }

    return array(
        'id' => $id,
        'form' => $form,
        'flashMessages' => $this->flashMessenger()->getMessages()
    );
}
```

When I not bind the address, it will flush to the user-entity, and when I bind the address, it flushes to address only, so my edits on the user won't work. How can I edit my form, with saving the user AND address?

Comment: In your form, **address** is a fieldset ?

Comment: Address is another entity, he allready bind the address to the form, so when i Edit a user, his address and user data shows up. But when I want to save it, it only saves the latest bind (address). I've to save both binds.